# Securing REST urls with Spring

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security

I have a working Spring REST web service and want to add basic authentication to it. The controller methods have normal url and HTTP method annotation attached to them. For adding security, I do two things

1) Add spring-security.xml to WEB-INF folder which looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">


    <security:http auto-config="true">
            <security:http-basic />
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
      <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
        <security:user name="spring" password="spring" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </security:user-service>
      </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

2) Configure spring security in web.xml as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

3) Spring controller:

```
package com.sample.main;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.sample.employee.Employee;

@Controller
public class EmpController 
{
    List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();  

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getEmp/{emp}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Employee getEmployee(@PathVariable("emp") int empid) {
        System.out.println("meet getEmp");
        for (Iterator<Employee> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Employee emp = (Employee) iterator.next();
            if(emp.getEmpId()==empid) {
                return emp;
            }
        }
        return new Employee();
    }
}
```

4) applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered as Spring beans.
     For example @Controller and @Service. Make sure to set the correct base-package-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sample" />

    <!-- Configures the annotation-driven Spring MVC Controller programming model.
    Note that, with Spring 3.0, this tag works in Servlet MVC only!  -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

5) spring-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

</beans>
```

I have uploaded the full application at:
http://www.javaexperience.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/SpringWebServiceSecurity.zip

After configuring springSecurityFilterChain, I start getting 404 error pages for REST urls in the application. Any ideas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the `url-mapping` of the dispatcher servlet to handle all requests.

**Web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Also in your security configuration change the security filter `intercept-url-pattern` to handle all requests.  This can be adjusted once working.

**spring-security.xml**

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:http-basic />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
</security:http>
```

Comment: ok. by doing that I do get a login form in web browser for GET requests and when I enter user as "spring" and password as "spring", I get 404 error page and the URL in web browser at that time is "http://localhost:8080/SpringWebServiceSecurity/getEmp/1/". This same url works if I remove security filter altogether from my app. Is some kind of redirect happening which is causing this issue.

Comment: @Sandeep, can you post the controller for the url?  Also, did you try this after changing the dispatcher servlet, without the security filter?  I suspect the configuration for Spring MVC may be off.  If you post your config I can take a look.

Comment: hey Kevin, I have added controller code and also applicationContext.xml file. In fact I have uploaded the app. zip at http://www.javaexperience.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/SpringWebServiceSecurity.zip

Comment: @Sandeep When you hit the url prior to implementing security, what did you receive?  Can you return an object when specifying @ResponseBody?

Comment: Yes without implementing security, it works without any issues.

Comment: I got it working by adding applicationContext.xml as part of contextConfigLocation parameter. Thanks for your help

Comment: Excellent Job!  Glad you got it figured out.

Comment: For anyone looking at this issue, please note that after authentication, spring again looks for controller stuff so it needs applicationContext on classpath. Hence the trouble. I was able to hit the controller methods without spring security and without adding applicationContext to classpath.